# Can you explain this code to me and why is work c++ prime numbers

Tags: c++

This code is to find the prime numbers from 3 to n, n being an input. this code works perfect but I need to understand it much more clearly mostly the part within the nested for loop.

```
 #include <iostream>


using namespace std;



int main () 
{
cout << "Please enter a number: \n";
int inputtedNumber;
cin >> inputtedNumber;
cout <<"the primes between 3 and that number are: \n";
int candidate = inputtedNumber;

 for (int i=3; i<candidate; i++) 
 {
    bool prime=true;
    for (int j=2; j*j<=i;j++)
    {
        if (i % j == 0) 
        {
            prime=false;
            break;    
        }
    }   
    if(prime) cout << i << "\n";
 }

    system("pause");
  return 0;
 }


  thank you!
```

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop looks at each number from 2 to the square root of `i`, to see if `i` is divisible by that number. If `i` is divisible by `j`, then `i%j` will be zero. If it finds a divisor, then we know it's not prime and can stop looking.

There's no need to go beyond the square root since, if there is a divisor larger than that, there must also be a corresponding divisor smaller than that, which will already have been found by this loop.

Comment: How does it know to go to the square root of i instead of just i?

Comment: @user2962910 Take the inequality `j <= sqrt(i)`, and square each side to get `j*j <= i`. That has the advantage that it's all done with integer arithmetic, with no complicated square-root calculations.

Answer (score 0):

This line is key.

```
    if (i % j == 0)
```

The `if` block is executed if `i` is divisible by `j`, which implies that `i` is not prime.

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to understand so if i initializes at 3 and J initializes at 2 and they keep going on a +1 basis how does this program not treat every number as prime?

Comment: The `%` operator returns the remainder of `i` divided by `j`. Obviously, if `i` is prime no `j` will divide it evenly. Also, the loop only checks up to the square root of `i` because after that you are testing numbers you have already tested.

Comment: @user2962910 `j` stops increasing before it gets past the square root of `i`. So if `i` is `3` (the first outer iteration) the inner loop never executes at all, because 2 is already more than sqrt(3)!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=3; i<candidate; i++)  // for every i between 3 and candidate
{
    bool prime=true;
    for (int j=2; j*j<=i;j++)  // for every j between 2 and the square root of i
    {
        if (i % j == 0) // if there is an i that is evenly divisible by j
        {
            prime=false; // set the flag
            break;    // break the inner loop
        }
    }   
    if(prime) cout << i << "\n"; // if i was a prime (no j's were evenly divisible), print it
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that cleared it up a bit, so the j*j part does not multiply j then?

Comment: It does not *change* `j`, it is stating that `j * j <= i`, which is mathematically equivalent to `j <= sqrt(i)`.  It is just more efficient to multiply than it is to take the square root.

Comment: Thank you that cleared it up perfectly I guess my math skills are a bit rusty.